# How to auto reload apps

Tags: android, ios, iphone, facebook

I'm just wondering how do apps like Facebook and Twitter automatically reload. For instance, if you get a message or a notification, you haven't requested it yourself. Is there a timer of sorts, or is there a smarter implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of google push notifications or android services  ?

Answer (score 1):

I think they use push notification.instead of reloading the whole view,they just update the updated or newest data.its my personnel view.

Answer (score 1):

They don't reload. They get notified of changes via push messaging. On Android usually via [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) (or [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/engage/gcm.html)). Once they get a notification and they need to update a `View` immediately from a background task they will likely use some sort of [message bus](http://square.github.io/otto/).

There is a background service within the Google Play Services app, that you'll need to have installed for this to work, that has a timer of sorts and that checks the google servers for new notifications to deliver. You could implement such a service yourself but it's bad for battery life if there is more than 1 service that checks for notifications.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.